# Initializing Node/Mongo App on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

So I just tried to push my Node/Mongo app on to Heroku. I haven't actually pushed the Mongo piece yet (but it's only needed for authentication, so it's not a big deal, I'd like to see the app running on Heroku w/ out it first).  I installed all of my `node modules` correctly and pushed to heroku, only to get this massive error (truncated of course).

Any idea what the problem is here?  I have a Procfile set up too.  Is it a problem with my port still being set to `3000`?

```
2014-08-20T21:15:06.978419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the auth@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979047+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the auth package,
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979385+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979552+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-20T21:15:06.979871+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls auth
2014-08-20T21:17:09.783316+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the auth@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-20T21:17:09.787373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-08-20T21:17:09.785003+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-08-20T21:17:09.785125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-08-20T21:17:09.783968+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```